# Videojs - Dashjs: Working Combination

Tags: video.js, dash.js

I use videojs v5.10.4, videojs-contrib-dash v2.3.0, and dashjs v2.1.1, but it doesn't work in Chrome. My server is Ubuntu 14.04 / Nignx 1.10.0 + rtmp module.

Does anyone know the versions of the working combination of Videojs, videojs-contrib-dash, and Dashjs?

Answer (score 0):

The following combinations are working for me:

videojs --- 5.9.2/5.10.7

videojs-contrib-dash --- 2.4.0

dashjs --- 2.3.0

Browser -- Chrome version 54.0.2840.71

The order of inclusion in the index.html should be *videojs*, followed by *dashjs* and then *videojs-contrib-dash*.